# toggleClass is not working, $ is not a function

Tags: jquery

i use blow code for toggle menu, but i have Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function error in console. do you have any idea?

my html code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/myfile/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-core-js'></script>

<nav class="navbar st_container">
            <div class="st-navlogo">
           <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="st-navholder">
                <div class="menu-toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav no-search">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
              <i class="fas fa-search" id="search-icon"></i>
              <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
            </ul>
            </div>
      </nav>
```

my js code:

```
$("#search-icon").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("search");
  $(".nav").toggleClass("no-search");
  $(".search-input").toggleClass("search-active");
});

$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
   $(".nav").toggleClass("mobile-nav");
   $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});
```

Comment: Is your jquery code location before or after your `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/` ? And is the jquery code located after your html?

Comment: Have you verified in the network tab of your browser's developer tools (F12) that jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: Wrap the script inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); if you haven't done it so far

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen jQuery file is in <head> and my js code in my footer

Comment: @connexo Yes, I use Wordpress and by defualt this file loaded in head of page.

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Tnx, I tried this too but there is still the problem.